# Preload sap.ui.unified.Calendar

Tags: sapui5

I'm testing my UI5 application's performance on a slow 3G connection. I've noticed that it takes quite some time to load the `sap.ui.unified.Calendar` for the first time when using the `sap.m.DateTimePicker`.

This is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DateTimePicker). The proposed solution is to preload the `sap.ui.unified` library. I have tried multiple ways of doing this but regardless of what I do, the `Calendar` still takes long to load the first time.

- I have tried adding `sap.ui.unified` to `data-sap-ui-libs` in my `index.html`.
- I have tried using `jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified")` (which is
  apparently deprecated).
- I have tried using `sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/unified/Calendar"])`.

None of these solutions work. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

The `DateTimePicker` is declared as follows in an XML View:

```
<DateTimePicker
    id="dtClockIn"
    valueFormat="MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm a"
    displayFormat="MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm a"
    placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm ampm"/>
```

There's nothing fancy happening in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.50 and below

Currently, library resource bundles (`messagebundle*.properties` files) are loaded **on-demand** and **synchronously** which creates a bottleneck before making use of the corresponding control (e.g. Calendar). I'm afraid we can't do much about it.

You could, however, at least prefetch the bundle file by calling [`getLibraryResourceBundle`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core/methods/getLibraryResourceBundle) manually when the UI is ready. E.g. on [`afterShow`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.NavContainerChild/events/AfterShow):

```js
onAfterShow: function() {
  sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sap.ui.unified");
  // Avoids fetching it later when the Calendar is about to be shown
},
```

---

### As of 1.52

[With v1.52](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/de0b47b0989508008134dea5a228eb1e6a3565fd), such bundles are loaded beforehand asynchronously as long as libraries are configured to be loaded asynchronously. Here is an example: https://output.jsbin.com/qolesuf

Comment: Calling `getLibraryResourceBundle` successfully pre-fetches the `messagebundle_en_US.properties` file, thanks! The `en.json` file still needs to be fetched when opening the Calendar but at least this almost halves the time. From what I understand though, `onAfterShow` can only be called on children of `NavContainer`. Since my `DateTimePicker` was just a child of a `View`, I used `onAfterRendering`.

Comment: @GianPaoloBuffo Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior that `en.json` gets fetched when opening the Calendar. If you share some code or info how I could reproduce the behavior, I'd gladly take a look into it to find out if we can pre-fetch the file as well.

Comment: @GianPaoloBuffo About `onAfterRendering`: I usually don't recommend doing anything there since it's unpredictable when and how often the hook is called exactly. If you have implemented navigation via `routing`, the `onAfterShow` or `onBeforeShow` on the `NavContainer` child (i.e. View) is a preferred hook. Here is an example of such implementation: [embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44](https://embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44/?show=controller/Parent.controller.js,preview)

Comment: @GianPaoloBuffo Related issue about locale data (`en.json`) being still loaded synchronously: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2345